# Replacing one char with many chars with using tr

Tags: bash, shell

```
  `echo "a~b" | tr '~' "=="`
```

This outputs a=b. But i wanted a==b.
How can i do this with using tr?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`tr` just can translate/delete characters.

Try something like this:

```
 echo "a~b" | sed 's/~/==/g'
```

Comment: echo "a~b" | sed 's/~/&=/g' in this case it doesn't work. How can i handle & chr?

Comment: echo "a~b" | sed 's/~/\&=/g' - escape it

Answer (score 14):

You can't with `tr`.

Instead, use bash string manipulation `${string/substring/replacement}`. Example:

```
str="a~b"
echo ${str/"~"/"=="}
```

Or use `sed`:

```
echo "a~b" | sed 's/~/==/'
```

Comment: tr translates all occurrences. To get that behavior with bash substring replacement, use two slashes: `str="a~b~c"; echo ${str//"~"/==}`

Answer (score 3):

You can't; tr can only map single characters. Use sed.